# How to write a purrr loop with required arguments

Tags: r, youtube-api, apply, purrr

I am trying to loop through a character vector of Youtube Video ID's, applying a function called list_caption_tracks from the 'tuber' package that would pull in the type of transcript the video has. I am getting an error related to specifying the required video_id argument in the list_caption_tracks function.

```
library(purrr)
library(tuber)

#list of youtube video IDs I want to loop through
videoid_list = c('5X1BELxYdws', 'J3Fv1pBNmFM','Oy0OD1iDi6s','QWd8szOzXgs', 'NBzmEx10xcc')

#function I want to apply to each ID - succesfully applied here to one object
list_caption_tracks(video_id = 'J3Fv1pBNmFM')

#trying to map through the ID list - throwing an error.
map(videoid_list, list_caption_tracks)
```

This throws an error "Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : Must specify a video ID." I'm struggling to figure out how to specify the video_id variable while successfully looping through the elements.

Here's what I tried:

```
map(videoid_list, list_caption_tracks, video_id = videoid_list)
```

This throws "Error in vapply(elements, encode, character(1)) : values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 5"

So I think I need to find a way to select each element when specifying the video_id but I couldn't figure this part out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a lambda function (`~`) and specify the argument 'video_id' with that in the `list_caption_tracks`

```
library(purrr)
out <- map(videoid_list, ~ list_caption_tracks(video_id = .x))
```